# Older versions of Python not found in conda-forge

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, arm64, conda-forge

I am trying to install Python 3.6.15 in a Conda virtual environment using `conda install -c conda-forge python=3.6.15` but keep getting the following error:

```
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.6.15

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-arm64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
```

I've tried appending conda-forge to my channels, to no avail. Also, creating a new virtual environment with `conda create -n OldTest python=3.6.15 anaconda` gives the same error. How might I install my desired version of Python using Conda?

Comment: Older versions are deprecated!

Comment: Ah, that's unfortunate. I'd avoid deprecated Python releases, but I'm trying to run an older version of TensorFlow for compatibility with a repo I'm working on. Is there a possible workaround?

Comment: There are no conda packages for M1 for that python version. But you could create an env that uses x64 python through rosetta

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have an environment that runs non-natively (i.e x64 through rosetta):

```
conda create -n oldTF
conda activate oldTF
conda config --env --set subdir osx-64
conda install python tensorflow=x.x #Only put the specific packages that you need here. Probably no reason to inlcude all of anaconda
```

Comment: I tried this solution and received an error reading, `The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/osx-64::__osx==12.4=0
  - feature:|@/osx-64::__osx==12.4=0
  - grpcio -> __osx[version='>=10.10|>=10.9']
  - tensorflow-deps -> grpcio[version='>=1.37.0,<2.0'] -> __osx[version='>=10.10|>=10.9']
`, in addition to numerous package conflicts. Is there a fix for this issue?

Comment: Which version of tensorflow are you trying to install. I would try adding `-c conda-forge` as a first guess